# If statement that is supposed to filter out newline not filtering new lines.

Tags: java, if-statement, newline

I'm writing a Regex pattern that filters through HTML tags and prints only the contents of valid tags for practice. While the pattern itself appears to be matching tags correctly, I am running into an issue when printing them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HTMLPattern{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

      while(testCases>0){
          String line = in.nextLine();
          String tagPattern = "<([^>]+)>([^<]*?)</\\1>";
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(tagPattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);
          Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
          if(m.find()){
              //checks if the output equals a newline
              if(m.group(2).matches("[\\n\\r]+")){
                   System.out.println("None");     
              }else{
                   System.out.println(m.group(2));
              }
          }else{
              System.out.println("None");
          }
         testCases--;
      }
   }
}
```

When inputting:

```
3
<a>test</a>
<b></b>
<c>test</c>
```

My output **should** be:

```
test
None
test
```

But **instead** it is:

```
test

test
```

**My question** is: Why is my if-statement not catching the newline and printing "None"?

Comment: I am not seeing a new line character in `<b></b>`. you should be testing for empty node value if you want it to print the output you are looking for

Comment: @Vimsha Hmm. I assumed it was a newline because all my previous attempts at checking for a null value failed.

Comment: @Vimsha Nvm, I just figured it out, I'll answer my question in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no new line, there is just empty string, try to match empty string like this:

```
if (m.group(2).matches("^$")) {
```

Or check `length` of string:

```
if (m.group(2).length() == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there are no newline(s) present in the if statement. While my previous attempts for checking `if(m.group(2) == null)` failed, the [.isEmpty()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_isempty.htm) method correctly matched the null value I was testing for:

```
if(m.find()){
   if(m.group(2).isEmpty()){
      System.out.println("None");     
      }else{
         System.out.println(m.group(2));
      }
   }else{
      System.out.println("None");
   }
```